# Acessando via curl

Tags: c#

Eu tenho o seguinte desafio:

Efetuar login em um site com os seguinte dados:

```
POST */kodoreq.php HTTP/1.1
Host: eofclub.in
Cookie: logado=sim
User-Agent: Lynx/3.15

usuario=desafio&senha=987654321&submit=sim
```

Já tentei em diversas formas e não consigo

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        string usuario = "desafio";
        string senha = "987654321";
        string submit = "sim";
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        Uri url = new Uri("http://eofclub.in/desafio/kodo/35p42s5436po63nnsr9o20rssp6647q3/kodoreq.php");
        UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        string postData = "{ \"usuario\" : \"" + usuario + "\", \"senha\": \"" + senha + "\", \"submit\": \"" + submit + "\"}";


        byte[] data = Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes(postData);

        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        Cookie usuarioCookie = new Cookie("logado", "sim", "/") { Domain = url.Host };
        cookieContainer.Add(usuarioCookie);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);            
        request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";            
        request.UserAgent = "Lynx/3.15";
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;


        Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        stream.Close();

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        stream = response.GetResponseStream();


        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());

        sr.Close();
        stream.Close();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Mas não consegue por que, especificamente?

Comment: Btw, não use code snnipets para código C#. Eles servem apenas para código client-side.

Comment: Ele sempre apresenta o erro "invalid".

Comment: A ideia do desafio é você chegar ao resultado... aqui fica a resposta, vai de você descobrir como obtê-la ou seguir a partir desse ponto...
proximo lvl ../o9ps9p2ro0n89r3n4o958rr7o7o01r9r/

Comment: Obrigado, mas de qualquer forma vou continuar tentando, obrigado pela ajuda @LeandroAngelo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Voce nao indicou o Header `User-Agent:`.
Secretamente parece que o servidor também está á espera do formato `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Aconselho também a usar o `HttpClient` que é a forma mais recente de fazer pedidos `HTTP`.

No seu código ficaria assim:

```
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.UserAgent = "Lynx/3.15";
```

Fica como desafio voce fazer o seu código usando o `HttpClient`

Comment: Eu tentei dessa forma, mas não conseguir, atualizei o código e de qualquer forma vou tentar com httpclient também

Comment: Conseguir fazer desta forma, comecei com httpClient para aprender